# Removing or toggling eventlistener on current tab

Tags: javascript

I need the current element with a class of "visible" to have **removeEeventListener** (whilst not being clickable) while other elements have **addEventListener**.

Basically, the current tab that is clicked on will have no event listener will the other tabs do. I am pretty close as the code below does remove the listener on a visible tab but does not add listeners to the others. Is this possible to do? Please no jQuery, thanks.

JS

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')
tabs.forEach(tab => {
    if (!tab.classList.contains('visible')) {
        tab.addEventListener('click', function handler() {
            let target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)
            tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
                tabContent.classList.remove('visible');
            });
            tabs.forEach(tab => {
                tab.classList.remove('visible');
            });
            tab.classList.add('visible');
            target.classList.add('visible');
            if (tab.classList.contains('visible')) {
                tab.removeEventListener('click', handler, true);
            } else {
                tab.addEventListener('click', handler, true);
            }
        }, true);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="tab-nav">
  <li class="tabnav visible" data-tab-target="#tab1">
    tab1
  </li>
  <li class="tabnav" data-tab-target="#tab2">
    tab2
  </li>
  <li class="tabnav" data-tab-target="#tab3">
    tab3
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab visible" data-tab-content>
    <p>Tab 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab" data-tab-content>
    <p>Tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab" data-tab-content>
    <p>Tab 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab { 
  display: none;
}

.visible.tab {
  display: block!important;
}
```

Comment: How about to have an early return from the event listener function if current tab is clicked and its visible? It will do the same thing no?

Comment: I used to do this by adding a class to the active tab and remove the event listener just for that class.

Comment: I was hoping that this would do the trick: "if (tab.classList.contains("visible"))"  as "visible" cycles through which ever tab is clicked. Am I supposed to add a nested if statement to add a class to "visible"? Also, adding a return seems to have no effect with or without, all eventlisteners permanently vanish if I click through them

Comment: Just updated the question for more clarity and slightly modified the JS, this is pretty much as close as I've got. @Mojo Allmighty very interested to hear your method if you can please elaborate?